# Run Java applet in context of a web application with local resources (JNLP file and jars)

Tags: java, applet, securityexception

Is it possible to run an applet in a Java web application which is based on a local (file system) JNLP file and depended Jars?

We have everything within the web application but due to performance issues we like to put the resources of the applet to the local file system.

Our first tests failed with a java.lang.Securityexception: Permission denied: null

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your jar file and before that edit your manifest file.follow steps given in following link to edit your manifest file and for siging your jar.

Links:

For editing manifest file:[Editing manifest file in jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html)

To sign your jar: [Siging jar doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Permission Attribute in manifest of Jar and Security attribute of JNLP should have the same value. as in if JNLP has all-permission then only manifest file should have all-permission in permission attribute. otherwise both shoudl have sanbox.